# Using a Different Naming Convention for Links in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

Is it possible to change what is considered "links" in D3? The JSON I receive from the server is set on being "nodes" and "edges" instead of "nodes" and "links". Here is a sample JSON:

```
{
"nodes": [
{"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "foo","idType":"USERNAME","color":"red"},"selected":false},
{"fixed":true,"data": {"id": "bar","idType":"USERNAME","color":"yellow"},"selected": false}
],
"edges": [
{"classes":null,"data":{"color":"blue","source":"foo","target":"bar","visible":true},"grabbable":false},
{"classes":null,"data":{"color":"green","source":"bar","target":"foo","visible":true},"grabbable":false}
]}
```

At first I thought it was declared from

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");
```

However when I change `.link` to `.edge` my code breaks.

```
// sets the source and target to use id instead of index
var edges = [];
root.edges.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = root.nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.source;
            })[0],
            targetNode = root.nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.target;
            })[0];

    // push the attributes in the JSON to the edges.
    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        label: e.data['label'],
        color: e.data['color']
    });
});

force
        .nodes(root.nodes)
        .links(edges)
        .start();

link = link
        .data(edges)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5);

node = node
        .data(root.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");
```

Comment: I don't think it matters what d3 calls it. How do you initialize your graph?

Comment: I'll update my question with the code. It's a little long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halcyon's comment about d3 not caring what you call `links` made me realize that my code isn't breaking from the actual initialization of the graph. It is breaking from the way I utilize the `id` as `source`/`target` instead of the default `index`.

Changing `root.links.forEach...` to `root.edges.forEach...` fixed the issue.